# Non-specific errors, no apparent cause

Tags: php

I am a newbie, working through exercises in 'Database Driven Websites'.

The following PHP gives two errors that a couple of hours of pondering and searching have not cleared up.

When I call the page from a browser I get:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/copydesign/www/listjokes.php on line 54

Line 54 is: "", which seems right to me.

In BBedit an error is indicated for line #51, which is a blank line. Line #50 is "?>" to indicate the end of PHP parsing. I hate to ask if I should be able to solve this for myself but if anyone can help me I'll be most appreciative.

---

Here is the entire page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>The CopyDesign Internet Joke Database</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php if (isset($_GET['addjoke'])): // Visitor wants to add a joke
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<label>Type a joke here:<br />
<textarea name="joketext" rows="10" cols="40">
</textarea></label><br />
</form>

<?php else: // Display default page

// Open a MySQL connection

$dbcnx = @mysql_connect('solas.phpwebhosting.com', 'copydesign', 'keylock');

// Select the joke database
if (!@mysql_select_db('ijdb')) {
exit('<p>Unable to connect to the joke database at this time.</p>');
}

?>

<p>CopyDesign's Internet Joke Database:</p>

<blockquote>

<?php

// Request the text of all the jokes
$result = @mysql_query('SELECT joketext FROM joke');
if (!result) {
exit('<p>Error performing query: ' . 
mysql_error() . '</p>');
}

// Display the text of each joke in a paragraph
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<p>' . $row['joketext'] . '</p>';
}

?>

</blockquote>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you indicate in your code where those lines are?

Answer (score 5):

You forgot a:

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

You have a `<? if(...): ?>` but with **no** end in site.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if (isset($_GET['addjoke'])):` is not closed with an `endif`. Close it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you didn't close your `<?php if:` `<?php else:` statement. "Unexpected $end" is usually inclusive of a bracket mis-match or code block ending too soon (and parser can't determine the end of the block)

Answer (score 0):

The error is very specific - it tells you that the interpreter got to the end of the script, when it expected to get to the end of an already opened block instead.

What I assume is that you are missing an [`endif`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)